# How to capture SQL query sent to Oracle server by web based application?

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

I am working on web based application and i need to know sql queries, sent by application server to Oracle server.

Comment: Well, configure the application to keep of log of such queries.

Comment: Its third party application and loggers are not set to show SQL queries.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You need to add more details. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.